# Remove point cloud from Potree/Threejs-scene

Tags: javascript, three-js, potree

I'm updating the cloud.js document while Potree is running on the client. When finished updating, I'd like to update the point cloud for the client. I tried to really update the client to re-read the cloud.js document, but cannot get it to work.

Now, as a workaround I'd like to remove the old pointcloud and add a new one using Potree.addPointcloud(). The second part works, but I want to delete the prevous version of the pointcloud. Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction.

I found something with the remove() method like scene.remove(pointcloud), but it's not recognized as a command.

Answer (score 1):

The point cloud data added into PotreeViewer can be accessed by using `viewer.scene.pointclouds` array. From this array, you can remove the previously added point cloud data. And If you want to show or hide the pointcloud then you can use the `visible` property of pointcloud object form `viewer.scene.pointclouds` array. E.g `viewer.scene.pointclouds[0].visible = true;` or `viewer.scene.pointclouds[0].visible = false;`.